# How can I remove "Publish as pages your manage" option

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

My app uses "publish_actions" and "manage_page" permissions in Facebook Graph API 2.2. On Facebook, users can see the corresponding "Post" and "Manage page" options in the app. With Facebook's recent upgrade to v2.3, users now also see "Publish as pages your manage" option even though the app does not use the new "publish_page" permission.  How can I have the "Publish as pages your manage" NOT show up in the app since the "publish_page" permissions is not being used?

Answer (score 1):

No, because it actually IS possible to "publish as pages you manage" if you authorize with `publish_actions` and `manage_pages`, so the message is there for a good reason.

Keep in mind that this is a very recent change, so it may still be a bit buggy. If you believe there´s something wrong, you should file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: But if a user un-checks the "Publish as pages you manage" option but not the "Post" (publish_actions) and "Manage page" (manage_pages) options, the app is still able to post to user's Facebook page. This may cause confusion for the user.

Comment: you should file a bug for that, i´ve edited my answer with a link